# Find the real roots of $\sqrt{x-2}(x^2-4x+3)=0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics, solution-verification

I thought the roots of this equation are $1,2,3$.

But the teacher says 1 is not a real root because if we take $x=1$ we get
$$\sqrt{-1}(0)$$

and $\sqrt{-1}$ is not real.
Is this right?

Comment: Yes, the teacher is basically right.

Comment: I have two inputs: (a) The domain of definition of the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{x-2}(x^2-4x+3)$$ does not include $1$.  (b) If you extend the domain of definition of $f$ to the whole $\mathbb{R}$ by allowing complex values, then $1$ is a root of $f$, and it is a real root ($1$ is clearly a real number).  So, the teacher is not technically correct.  What should be said is that $1$ is not a root in the domain of definition.

Comment: If this is a valid objection to a real root, why is it acceptable to solve cubic equations with three real roots by a method which necessarily involves complex numbers in the intermediate steps?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true $x=1$ is a root, the question is: what is the domain in which the equation "exists"?
The answer is that the square root only exists if you consider the inequality  $x-2\ge 0$.  Otherwise your solution does not compile, so to speak.
So the roots coexisting within your domain are $2$ and $3$.

Comment: But the domain of the equation was not mentioned so how can you say 1 is not in the domain.

Comment: When you have a root the domain is automatically implied. It is the same as if 1/(1-x) is implied that x does not equal 1 in the domain.

Comment: you said that we need to consider the inequality $x-2≥0$. But even if we take $x=1$ the answer is 0 because the square root is multiplied by 0.

Comment: It is 0, but only because $i*0=0$ and that is not in the domain of $R$, but the entity $0+0*i$ under $C$

Answer (score -1):

We have indeed 3 roots: 1,2 and 3. But now we are looking for the real roots. And yes 1 is not a real root, because like you said $\sqrt -1$ is not real, it is imaginary.